# Spring Framework & DHTMLX

Tags: spring, dhtmlx

I am new here to Stackoverflow, so bear with me. The question is that I have tried DhtmlxGantt with Node.js alongside with server-side integration. Here is a tutorial that I followed in order to do that https://dhtmlx.com/blog/video-tutorial-create-javascript-gantt-chart-node-js/. All I want to do now is to integrate this DhtmlxGantt into Spring Framework, but I can hardly find any good examples. Please help me out, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DthmlxGantt has a ajax method which can make calls to a backend restcontroller in spring.

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_ajax_other.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't specialize in Java, but Gantt is a Javascript application, it should work on any HTML page. So, you just need to get a ready Java Demo, and add the necessary code to load Gantt:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__initializing_gantt_chart.html

I found the following guide and demo:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/#initial

If you run it, you get a standard `Hello World` page.
To add Gantt, you need to modify the `src/main/resources/static/index.html` file.

Here is a ready demo with DHTMLX Gantt:

https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/52f7092dd08bfdc13c5d3f280ec24a26/Spring+Gantt_demo.zip

To see how it works, you need to install all the necessary components of OpenJDK 8 (or other Java version). Then you need to navigate to the folder with that demo project in the command line and run the following command:

Linux:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

Windows:

```
gradlew.bat bootRun
```